# Dict construction with elements in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list `['a','b','c','d']`. I need to construct a `dict` out of this list with all the elements of the list as keys in the dict with some default value for all the elements such as `None`.

How to do that? Should I need to write a function for that or is there a constructor available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`dict.fromkeys()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesmapping.html).

`dict.fromkeys(['a','b','c','d'])` will return a dictionary with `None` for all of its values.

`dict.fromkeys(['a','b','c','d'], foo)` will return a dictionary with `foo` for all of its values.

Comment: You're answer I like better than mine. Good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator to quickly convert it to a dictionary:

```
dict((x, None) for x in L)
```

(Where L is your list)

That results in:

```
{'a': None, 'c': None, 'b': None, 'd': None}
```

Comment: Go see Gabe's idea. It utilizes a built in function and is sufficiently faster.

Comment: This way is appropriate if you need the dict values to be separate objects (although with the same value). See also the OP's follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592592/setting-a-value-to-a-dictionarys-dictionary-value

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
dict.fromkeys(data, default_value)
```

If you omit `default_value`, it defaults to `None`.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d']

# using list comprehension
d = dict([(x, None) for x in lst])

# using fromkeys
d = dict.fromkeys(lst)
```