# Setting a value to a dictionary's dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

The code:

```
>>> mydict = {}
>>> keylist = ['a','b','c']
>>> mydict=dict.fromkeys(keylist,{})
>>> mydict['a']['sample'] = 1
>>> mydict
{'a': {'sample': 1}, 'c': {'sample': 1}, 'b': {'sample': 1}}
```

I was expecting `mydict['a']['sample'] = 1` would set the value just for a's dictionary value and would get this: `{'a': {'sample': 1}, 'c': {}, 'b': {}}`.

What am I missing here? What should I have to do to get the expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you added the *same* dictionary to mydict for every key. You want to add different dictionaries, like so:

```
mydict = dict((key, {}) for key in keylist)
```

In the above code, you create a new dictionary to pair with each key. In your original code, the function fromkeys took the argument (the empty dictionary you provided) and added that exact argument - that single empty dictionary you created to pass in to the function - to each of the keys. When that one dictionary was changed, then, that change showed up everywhere.